# Displaying nested data from firebase to ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display nested data from Firebase to Ionic project.
I have the following data structure in firebase:

[image]

My query:

```
let dbRefLists = firebase.database().ref('lists/');
var self = this; 
dbRefLists.on('value', (querySnapshot) => {
    this.lists = Object.keys(querySnapshot.val()).map(key => querySnapshot.val()[key]);
    querySnapshot.forEach((data) => {
      var listItem = data.val().id;
      dbRefLists.child(`${listItem}/listItems`).on('value', (snapshotVal) => {
        if (snapshotVal.val() !== null) {
          self.lists.listItems = Object.keys(snapshotVal.val()).map(key => snapshotVal.val()[key]);
        }
      })
      return self.lists.listItems;
    })
    return lists;
});
```

My HTML:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let list of lists; let i=index" text-wrap (click)="toggleGroup(i)" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(i)}">
    <h2>
      <span>{{list.title}}</span> 
    </h2>
    <ul *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">
      <li *ngFor="let listItem of lists.listItems">
        <span>{{listItem.title}}</span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The result is that I receive list items in all the lists (List1 and List2), instead of only in List1:

[image]

Where is my mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you flatten your data base structure like this:

[image: database structure]

queuing will become much easier. 
First let me create classes, they will be in the Firebase service file that showed below:

```
export class myList {
  listId: string
  elClass: string;
  title: string;
  items?: myItem[];

  constructor(listId: string,elClass: string,title: string, items?: myItem[]){
    this.listId=listId;
    this.elClass=elClass;
    this.title=title;
    if(items){
      this.items = items;
    }
  }
}

export class myItem {
  listId: string;
  title: string;

  constructor(listId: string,title: string){
    this.listId=listId;
    this.title=title;
  }
}
```

Getting the data:

```
data: myList[] = [];

onGetListsWithItems(){
  let ref = firebase.database().ref('/');

  ref.child('lists/').on('child_added', (snapshot)=>{
    let list: myList = new myList(snapshot.key, snapshot.val().elClass, snapshot.val().title);
    let items: myItem[] = [];
    let listId = snapshot.key;
    ref.child('listItems/')
      .orderByChild('listId')
      .equalTo(listId)
      .on('child_added', (item)=>{
        items.push(new myItem(item.val().listId, item.val().title));
      });
    list.items = items;
    this.data.push(list);
  });
}
```

This will give you(console.log of data):

```
[myList, myList]
0:{
  elClass:"inActive",
  listId:"randomlistId1",
  title:"List1",
  items: {
    0:{
      listId:"randomlistId1",
      title:"Item2"},
    1:{
      listId:"randomlistId1",
      title:"Item1"}
},
1:{
  elClass:"inActive",
  listId:"randomlistId2",
  title:"List2",
  items:{ 
    0:{
      listId:"randomlistId2",
      title:"Item2"}
}
```

and finally you can display it in HTML like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let list of data">
    <h3>{{list.title}}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of list.items">
        <p>{{item.title}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the result looks like this:

[image: printed result]

Let me know if you will need any comments thought the code or you will have any questions.

P.S. You can read about flatting the database here
[new docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data?authuser=0) and here [old docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html)

Comment: Thanks @Arttu, your solution works perfect. I changed my database structure and obviously flatten data base structures are better to quering. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is still place for improvements. For example by using Observables. But I am new to ionic and I am not sure how it will behave with them. That is why I gave a simpler version.